# Calculate how many variable

Tags: sas

i want to Calculate how many variable and out put in log

i want use do loop

this is my Program

```
%PUT _USER_;
```

`OPTIONS MPRINT;`

```
%MACRO varnum(a);
data d;
array a &a. ;
%do i=1 %to %str(dim(a)-1);
%put there are &i variables;
%end;
run;
%MEND;
%varnum(age  income   educ)
```

thanks

Comment: why do you do this, you input 3 variables so 3 should come out, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Dirk that this is probably not a good idea, but it's fairly trivial.  There are some good reasons for this; primarily, using a parameter list with unknown parameter count.  If you want to see a more thorough usage, look up SYSPARM ( http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543608.htm ) which usually requires this sort of manipulation (and is probably the correct way to handle the unknown number of parameters issue, although this isn't really any different).

```
%MACRO varnum(a);
data d;
array a &a. ;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countc(%sysfunc(compbl(&a)),%str( )))+1; 
*First COMPBL (remove extra spaces) to ensure one space between parameters;
*Then count the number of spaces between parameters, and add one since (1 2 3) has 2 spaces;
%put there are &i variables;
%end;
run;
%MEND;
%varnum(age  income   educ)
```